# Why does babel-node not support module loading in the REPL?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, read-eval-print-loop

It's established that [babel-node doesn't support module loading in the REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36197012/babel-node-es6-modules-arent-supported-in-the-repl).   In the [documentation](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) it simply says this:

> Due to technical limitations ES6-style module-loading is not fully supported in a babel-node REPL.

My question is why?  If I wrote a tiny script named `t.js` and ran it with babel-node, then import statements would work fine. What is the effective difference between a REPL which reads source code a line at a time from standard in, and `babel-node t.js` which reads source code from a file?

Does anyone know if there are plans to support `import` in the future, as lack of `import` kinda kills the REPL?

Comment: There simply is no hook for transpilers in the repl, while it's relatively simple to transpile a file before executing it with node.

Comment: Also `import` statements only work statically on the module level, where they transpile as a whole. Doing something similar in a REPL would be quite different. The `const` declaration has similar problems.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "there is no hook for transpilers in the repl"?  How does this work in files then?  Not sure if my mental model is right, but I'm imaging babel-node is mostly transpiring to es5 then running that with regular node from memory or from a tempfile, is that right?

Comment: Yes, it's first transpiling them externally then running regular node on it. IIRC, for `require` calls there is a hook in node so babel can register a transpile-on-the-fly for dynamically required files. But when regular node already is running a regular repl, there's no way to transpile the user input. Or at least its way more complicated than just transpiling a file.

Comment: You guys know if there was any progress on that in the last couple of years? Because if I work on a modern node js app with es6 style imports, the repl is close to useless... Unless of course I manually require deps and manually copy/paste my fns into the repl.

Comment: @AlexanderF. with the velocity of JS since this question was asked -- if possible I just wouldn't use babel anymore at all and just use regular node.