# Using lodash module in babel-node REPL?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, lodash

I am trying to test lodash, and apparently the following line won't work in the REPL:

```
import curry from 'lodash/curry';
```

See, e.g., [babel-node es6 "Modules aren't supported in the REPL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36197012)
[Why does babel-node not support module loading in the REPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064755/)

Is there a way that I can pre-load a module like lodash into babel-node? (e.g. via a command line option or a configuration file)

If not, is there another way of evaluating ES6 with lodash preloaded?

So far, I've tried the online REPL at https://babeljs.io/repl/, and evaluation in the Console in Firefox. None worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import` surely won't work, because the package should be installed first and bundled in order to be imported, which isn't the duty of Babel REPL.

Lodash is already loaded and used in Babel REPL, [it can be used in REPL as `_` global](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=const%20%7B%20curry%20%7D%20%3D%20_%3B%0A&%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.patchwork%28definition,%20context%29;%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%0A%09configure%20=%20function%28config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09for%20%28var%20key%20in%20config%20||%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20%28key%20in%20this._config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this._config[key]%20%3D%20config[key]%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09debug%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20||%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.debug%20||%20console.log%20||%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09warn%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20||%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.warn%20||%20console.log%20||%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patch%20%3D%20function%20patch%28origFn%2C%20patchFns%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09name%20%3D%20name%20||%20%27%27%3B%0A%0A%09%09var%20wrapper%20%3D%20function%20patchWrapper%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20patch%20functions%20can%20substitute%20original%20args%20and%20result%0A%09%09%09var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20args%3A%20Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns%20&%20patchFns.length%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.pre%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Prepatched%20@%20%27%20+%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.pre.apply%28this,%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.over%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Overridden%20@%20%27%20+%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20=%20patchFns.over.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Postpatched%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.post.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Passed%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09callbackFn%28obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09return%20obj.result%3B%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09wrapper.pachted%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20double-pachting%20control%0A%09%09return%20wrapper%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pre%20%3D%20function%20pre%28origFn%2C%20preFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20preFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09post%20%3D%20function%20post%28origFn%2C%20postFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20post%3A%20postFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09over%20%3D%20function%20over%28origFn%2C%20overFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20over%3A%20overFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pass%20%3D%20function%20pass%28origFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patchwork%20%3D%20function%20patchwork%28tree%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%28function%20process%28nodes%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09for%20%28var%20nodeName%20in%20nodes%20||%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20node%20%3D%20nodes[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20origFn%20%3D%20context[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%0A%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27origFn%27%2C%20origFn]%2C%20[%27context%27%2C%20context]%2C%20[%27nodes%27%2C%20nodes]%2C%20[%27nodeName%27%2C%20nodeName]%29%0A%0A%09%09%09%09var%20callbackFn%20%3D%20!node.then%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20function%20%28obj%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28%27process%27%2C%20obj%29%0A%09%09%09%09%09process%28node.then%2C%20obj.result%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28!%28%27pachted%27%20in%20origFn%29%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20%28node.pre%20||%20node.over%20||%20node.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20node.pre%2C%20over%3A%20node.over%2C%20post%3A%20node.post%20%7D%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27context[nodeName]%27%2C%20context[nodeName]]%2C%20[%27nodes[nodeName]%27%2C%20nodes[nodeName]]%29%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%29%28tree%2C%20context%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D&%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.patchwork%28definition,%20context%29;%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%0A%09configure%20=%20function%28config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09for%20%28var%20key%20in%20config%20||%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20%28key%20in%20this._config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this._config[key]%20%3D%20config[key]%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09debug%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20||%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.debug%20||%20console.log%20||%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09warn%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20||%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.warn%20||%20console.log%20||%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patch%20%3D%20function%20patch%28origFn%2C%20patchFns%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09name%20%3D%20name%20||%20%27%27%3B%0A%0A%09%09var%20wrapper%20%3D%20function%20patchWrapper%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20patch%20functions%20can%20substitute%20original%20args%20and%20result%0A%09%09%09var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20args%3A%20Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns%20&%20patchFns.length%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.pre%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Prepatched%20@%20%27%20+%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.pre.apply%28this,%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.over%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Overridden%20@%20%27%20+%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20=%20patchFns.over.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Postpatched%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.post.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Passed%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09callbackFn%28obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09return%20obj.result%3B%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09wrapper.pachted%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20double-pachting%20control%0A%09%09return%20wrapper%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pre%20%3D%20function%20pre%28origFn%2C%20preFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20preFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09post%20%3D%20function%20post%28origFn%2C%20postFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20post%3A%20postFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09over%20%3D%20function%20over%28origFn%2C%20overFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20over%3A%20overFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pass%20%3D%20function%20pass%28origFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patchwork%20%3D%20function%20patchwork%28tree%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%28function%20process%28nodes%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09for%20%28var%20nodeName%20in%20nodes%20||%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20node%20%3D%20nodes[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20origFn%20%3D%20context[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%0A%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27origFn%27%2C%20origFn]%2C%20[%27context%27%2C%20context]%2C%20[%27nodes%27%2C%20nodes]%2C%20[%27nodeName%27%2C%20nodeName]%29%0A%0A%09%09%09%09var%20callbackFn%20%3D%20!node.then%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20function%20%28obj%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28%27process%27%2C%20obj%29%0A%09%09%09%09%09process%28node.then%2C%20obj.result%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28!%28%27pachted%27%20in%20origFn%29%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20%28node.pre%20||%20node.over%20||%20node.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20node.pre%2C%20over%3A%20node.over%2C%20post%3A%20node.post%20%7D%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27context[nodeName]%27%2C%20context[nodeName]]%2C%20[%27nodes[nodeName]%27%2C%20nodes[nodeName]]%29%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%29%28tree%2C%20context%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D):

```
const { curry } = _;
```

If the question isn't limited to Lodash, the quickest way to get third-party library in REPL is to load the script manually. And since Babel website has jQuery loaded (as almost any website), the shortest way to do this is `jQuery.getScript`, in console:

```
$.getScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js');
```

After that Lodash `_` global becomes available in REPL.

The whole code can be wrapped with callback to skip console part:

```
$.getScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js', () => {
  console.log(_.VERSION);
});
```

babel-node REPL doesn't support imports, as the links in the original post say. Instead, `require` should be used, like anywhere else in Node.

```
var { curry } = require('lodash')
```

This requires to have `lodash` installed in `node_modules` that exists in current working directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using `babel-node --presets es2015`, and when executing `> const { curry } = _;`, I got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'curry' of undefined
    at repl:4:17 ...
` Any suggestions?

Comment: The answer addressed Babel REPL in the first place. Sure, there's no `_` global in babel-node. You should just `require`, like usually in Node.